# object construction with assignment operator

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I am wondering that object construction with assignment operator works, never seen that before I saw this question:

[return by value calls copy ctor instead of move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46628553/return-by-value-calls-copy-ctor-instead-of-move)

Reduced example code:

```
class A
{
    public:
        int x;
        A(int _x):x(_x){ std::cout << "Init" << std::endl;}
        void Print() { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
        A& operator = ( const int ) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    A a=9;
    a.Print();
}
```

Is writing of

```
A a(9);
A a{9};
A a=9;
```

all the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with assignment operator, it's initialization, more precisely [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), which just uses the equals sign in the initializer.

> when a named variable (automatic, static, or thread-local) of a non-reference type `T` is declared with the initializer consisting of an equals sign followed by an expression.

For `A a = 9;` the approriate constructor (i.e. `A::A(int)`) will be invoked to construct `a`. <sup>1</sup>

`A a(9);` is [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), `A a{9};` is [direct list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11), they all cause the `A::A(int)` to be invoked to construct the object for this case. <sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Before C++17 the appropriate move/copy constructor is still required conceptually. Even though it might be optimized out but still has to be accessible. Since C++17 this is not required again.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Note that there're still subtle differences among these initialization styles, they may lead to different effects in some specialized cases.</sub>

Comment: Ah! So by deleting `A(const A&) = delete;` it fails. Got it ;)

Comment: @Klaus Note that it only happens before C++17; from C++17 the appropriate constructor (move or copy) is not required to be accessible again. [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gBR0MNwgnnpK5NVA)

Comment: I would add that `A{9}` will prefer the constructor with `std::initializer_list` when available over `A(int)`, while A(9) will always use `A(int)`